# Как выделить память под 2-мерный динамический массив

Tags: c++, массивы, память, динамические-массивы

Есть такой класс:

```
class Field
{
public:
    Field(sf::Vector2<int> size);
    ~Field();
    sf::Vector2<int> size;
    bool* tileState;
private:

};

Field::Field(sf::Vector2<int> size)
{
    this->size = size;
    this->tileState = new bool[this->size.x][this->size.y]{};

}

Field::~Field()
{
    //пока удалять не буду
}
```

Проблема в том что я не могу выделить двумерный массив в конструкторе а больше никак, в чем проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что в C++ нет двумерных масивов, вместо них - массивы массивов (то есть тип поля - `bool**`). Соответственно, нужно выделить сначала память для одного измерения, затем - для другого:

```
this->tileState = new bool*[this->size.x];

for (int i=0; i < this->size.x; ++i)
    this->tileState[i] = new bool[this->size.y];
```

Очищать память нужно аналогично, в обратном порядке.

Comment: Двумерных массивов вообше нет нигде,  это  просто абстракция такая

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, речь идет про синтаксические конструкции языка.

Comment: @ free_ze,  а я о том, что не только в С++...

Answer (score 1):

Массив NxM.

Часто это делают так:

```
type ** array = new type*[N];
for(size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) array[i] = new type[M];
```

Еще вариант -

```
type * array = new type[N*M];
```

Но тогда нужно помнить, что вместо `array[i][j]` нужно писать `array[i*M+j]`.

Но проще всего - вектор векторов:

```
vector<vector<type>>array(N,vector<type>(M));
```

Можно, конечно, и динамически... но раз это делается в конструкторе - то нет смысла.

```
class Type {
    vector<vector<type>> array;
    ...
    Type(int N, int M):array(N,vector<type>(M)){}
```

Примерно так. А в самом классе тогда очень простое обращение - `array[i][j]` без разыменований.

Если размеры известны во время компиляции - можно подумать о применении `array<type>`.

Comment: А вот так это плохо? `new bool[this->size.x]{ new bool[this->size.y]{} };`

Comment: А так вообще не получится.

Comment: У меня получается

Comment: У вас *компилируется*, но не получается... Попробуйте с ним поработать.

Comment: Проблема в том что размеры неизвестны

Comment: Не в размерах дело. Вы только *первому* элементу присвоите значение, возвращаемое `new`, остальные будут нулевыми указателями: https://ideone.com/BBIcZE А в самом классе - N и M - не константы - гляньте, я конструктор подправил...